# it's possible to do transactions through http requests in perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, transactions, dbi

I'm doing a web application and i want to do is if user don't like the changes or he makes a mistake, he could rollback the changes, and if he likes, save it. I'm using Perl with DBI module and MySQL.
First I send the data to update to a other Perl file, in that page I perform the update and i return the flow to the first page and show the changes to the user.
So I am wondering if its possible to persist or keep alive the transaction through HTTP request or how to do the transaction?
I did the following:

```
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
$dbh-do("update ...")
```

I'm a beginner with Perl and DBI so any answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How complex a transaction is it? One table, or multiple tables and complex relationships?

If it's a single table, it might be a lot simpler for the confirmation page to show the *before* (DBI) values and the *after* (form) values, and perform the transaction following a 'commit' from there.

Apache::DBI and other ORM modules do exist that attempt to persist database connections, but given each web-server process has its own memory-space, you quickly get into some pretty hairy problems. Not for the noob, I would suggest.

I would also recommend that before you go too far with hand-crafted DBI, have a look at some of the object-relational mapping modules out there. [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~arodland/DBIx-Class-0.08196/lib/DBIx/Class.pm) is the most popular/actively maintained one.